# Why is debugging ultra slow in Visual Studio 2010 when stepping through Excel interop code?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, excel

To nip this in the bud, I have posted this question and workaround. I would like to accept an answer that actually quantitatively describes the problem.

I do some office programming using VS2010 and VB.NET. I have found that using VB.NET over VBA provides a much better user experience for office automation tasks. But, VB.NET IDE sometimes, not all the time, grinds to a halt when debugging Excel COM interop code, such as it takes 5 minutes to set a string equal to the value of cell, or just removing and adding breakpoints takes minutes apiece. This has been the bane of my existence for sometime, as I would have to restart my computer to fix it, but I have finally figured out the causal actions and a workaround. It happens when I have more than one other Excel instance open besides the COM server. I know Excel usually only opens one EXCEL.EXE, but, I have my registry settings so that every excel document opens in a new instance, so that I can look at separate docs on separate monitors. I don't believe this is uncommon. So, when I have left Excels open and my app starts an Excel COM server and breaks into the debugger, this is when the problem occurs, but also only if I click or operate in someway in one of the Excels after starting the COM server. Then it is like the COM server gets confused as a chameleon in a bag of Skittles of which it can't get out until I restart the computer. So, does anyone have enough debugging, COM, and  Interop expertise to tell me what is causing this debugging hell? And possibly a way to preempt it?

Comment: Terminating a debug session without a normal shutdown of the CLR will leave the Office program running.  This can quickly build up in a typical iterative debug session.  And has side-effects, Office programs are "heavy".  Keep Task Manager handy, forcibly terminate the process when you quit debugging.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To workaround this problem without restarting, I have found that I can end all instances of EXCEL.EXE, even the COM server, and close the IDE, then reopen Excel directly without a document and close it. Now, reopen the IDE, run code, start debugging, and stepping latency is non-existent or negligible.